# How do I get my GAE website to run with my own domain such as http://www.mysite.com

Tags: google-app-engine, web-hosting

I finally finished creating my first website for the app engine. Everything is running fine on `mysite.appspot.com`. Now I have an existing domain with Godaddy that I want to use as my GAE website's domain. Basically I have been going in circles trying to get that part done.

When I go to `Application Settings` > `Add Domain` and type my domain, I get a 404. I am not really sure why. But I guess I need to first  prove that I already own my domain? How do I do that?

The links keep sending me to either http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/ or https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/domains. But there is nothing there to resolve my problem.

Do I need a business account in order to host my website on GAE with my own `mysite.com` domain as opposed to the `mysite.appspot.com` domain?

If anyone has recently successfully navigated that process please share the details. Quite frankly, after spinning around so much, I am even sure what the right questions are:

How do I get my GAE website to run with my own domain such as `http://www.mysite.com`

Answer (score 1):

google recently discontinued its free version of apps for business. but that is what i used. if you signed up for apps for business prior to last week, the free version, you can use that

https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/domains

let us know how it goes ... good luck